# Can't dismiss UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

Edit: I just figured out the problem is UIImagePicker and not video editor changing code to represent that.

I am trying to make it so when they hit the cancel button on the UIImagepicker it will dismiss it and will logout of Facebook and go to the main view.

This is what I have to dismiss.

```
    -(IBAction)Logout:(id)sender
{
    [[FBSession activeSession]closeAndClearTokenInformation ];
    [self.parentViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(YES)];
}
```

and here is how i present the image picker

```
//Create an image picker
    UIImagePickerController* imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = self;
    //Get the videos from the photo library
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    //Set media types to movie tyeps
    imagePicker.mediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:(NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    //present the controller

    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

The error I am getting is erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSURL initFileURLWithPath:isDirectory:]: nil string parameter'

I am not even using initFileURLWithPath anywhere in my program so I have no idea what the problem seems to be right now. I have narrowed it down that the dismiss is causing the the error to happen and I'm not sure what is going wrong right now. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem. The code that was wrong was not part of the code posted. Basically i was trying to assign a url(that was nil) to another url and thats what was causing the error. The error message is still kinda of ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

Within your header file for your viewController you should already have the following delegates implemented

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>
```

This will allow you access to the UIImagePickerController's delegate methods which will fire once the UIImagePicker cancel button has been pressed. One of these methods is the one below `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo`. You will need to add this method and dismiss the picker from here.

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{

//Within this method you can capture/save etc the media you have just recorded etc too.

//Use the line below to dismiss the pickerController

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: I have all that. I should have included that in my code but yea i got all that in my code. The problem is when the user hits the cancel button and it hits the dismiss it breaks with the error i posted above.